# How to create a full orphan copy of a current branch in git?

Tags: git

Let's say I have something like this:
`git log --oneline --graph --decorate`

```
* 286f295 (HEAD -> Super_Branch) Adding super file
* bdeddb8 (origin/empty_base, empty_base) Initial commit
```

I want make Super_Branch an orphan and create a copy of each commit in that branch.
`git subtree split` does something similar but it extracts a history of some path to an orphan branch; I just want to make existing branch orphaned.

Ideally I don't want to use `git checkout` or `git checkout --orphan` cause I don't want to change current HEAD.

Comment: This appears to be missing the understanding of what a branch is in Git: Commits do not _belong_ to a branch. It’s more that branches just point to a commit within the (usually connected) history graph. So if you make a copy of a branch, that copy will just point to the same thing. – If you wanted to make a separate copy of a branch with “separate commit copies”, then those commit copies would have to be actually *different* from the original ones in order for this to work.

Comment: Sure; I want to generate a copy of a commit with the same contents but with different SHA and different parent. As I said, subtree split does something similar.

Answer (score 3):

An *orphan branch* doesn't really exist.  Really, seriously, it doesn't.  That's kind of what makes it an orphan branch.  I think maybe what you want is to create a new *root commit*.  There are several ways to do that, but before we get there, I need to provide the right background.

As [poke commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59159395/how-to-create-a-full-orphan-copy-of-a-current-branch-in-git#comment104543142_59159395), Git is a little weird here.  Commits exist by themselves.  They are very real entities, with their own separate existence.  Each commit has its own unique name—its big ugly hash ID—by which you (or Git) can access *that particular commit* at any time.  And, each commit stores some data—a snapshot of all of your files—and some metadata, such as your name and email address and a timestamp (or actually two of these).

One of the metadata items in each commit is a list of parent hash IDs.  This list most often has just one entry in it.  When we come across such a commit—a very ordinary one—we like to look at it by comparing it to its parent.  That's what `git log -p` or `git show` does: they first print out the metadata, formatted suitably so that we see who *made* the commit and when, then run `git diff` on the snapshot stored in the parent and the snapshot in this commit, to see what is different in the two.  From that, we infer that whoever made the commit, made those changes.

A merge commit is simply any commit with at least *two* parents.  Because it does have two parents, we can't just compare it with its (single) parent to see what changed.  So `git log -p` just shows the metadata, then moves on to show both parents (though one at a time) without attempting a diff.<sup>1</sup>

So that covers commits with one parent (ordinary) and with two or more (merges).  That leaves only one possible case: a commit with *no* parent.  A commit with *no* parent is a *root commit*.  When `git log -p` goes to show a root commit, it shows the metadata as usual, then does a diff against Git's special [empty tree](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9765453/1256452), so that it looks as though all files were added in that commit.  (After all, they were.)

---

<sup>1</sup>The `git show` command *does* attempt a diff, and does it using the *combined diff* trick.  This doesn't show what changed!  It can't, really.  So instead, it shows some *subset* of changes as a result of combining each diff against each parent.  For any parent-vs-child comparison pair in which some file *didn't* change, it shows nothing at all.  For those files that, in the child, are different from *all* parents, it mushes together each of the parent-vs-child diffs into the combined diff.  Some stuff gets tossed out of this as well, and mostly, you get a view into the areas where someone may have had to resolve conflicts.

This *is* useful, but it doesn't tell you what actually *changed*.  To find out what changed vs one of the parents, use `--first-parent` or `-m` or an explicit `git diff` of the chosen parent vs the child.

---

#### The first commit in a new, empty repository is always a root commit

When you make a new, totally-empty repository:

```
mkdir somedir; cd somedir; git init
```

you get a repository that has *no* commits, and *no branch names* either.  That's because in Git, a branch *name* like `master` *must* hold the raw hash ID of some existing commit.  There are no existing commits, so there can be no branch names.

Nonetheless, if you run `git status`, Git will say that you are `on branch master`.  How can you be on a branch that does not exist?

The answer is: this branch is an *orphan branch*.  It does not exist, yet you are on it.

If you use `git checkout -b other` to switch from the nonexistent branch `master` to the new nonexistent branch `other`, `git status` will now say `on branch other`.  You continue to be on a branch that does not exist—an orphan branch—and there continue to be no commits.

Until you actually *make* a commit, no branch can exist.  So you can *only* be on an orphan branch, at this point.  The `git checkout -b` command will keep creating orphan branches, and since orphan branches don't actually exist, the old orphan branch that you *were* on continues to lack existence, and is not shown by `git branch`, for instance.<sup>2</sup>

Whenever you are in this state—of being on a branch that does not exist, i.e., an "orphan" branch—the *next* commit you make will be a *root commit*.  That is, it will be a commit with *no* parent (and, like all new commits, a new unique hash ID).  Now that this *commit* exists, Git can finally create the branch name.  So it takes the orphan branch name that is being remembered via `HEAD`, and creates the branch name, pointing to the new root commit.  And now you have a real branch name—a regular, ordinary branch name that *does* exist and *will* be shown by `git branch`.

---

<sup>2</sup>Underneath it all, this weird state of affairs is really quite simple.  The file `.git/HEAD`, which holds the *name* of the current branch, just keeps getting updated in place.  No branches are created!  We just stuff a new *name* into `.git/HEAD`, without doing anything else.

---

#### `git checkout --orphan name` re-creates this weird state

If you run:

```
git checkout -b branch-X
```

Git creates the branch name `branch-X` pointing to the *current commit*.  The branch now exists.  The branch name holds the hash ID of the current commit—and, of course, Git attaches `HEAD` to the new name (i.e., writes the name `branch-X` into `.git/HEAD` or, if this is an added work-tree, some other more-appropriate file).

But if you run:

```
git checkout --orphan branch-X
```

Git *doesn't* create the branch name.  Instead, it attaches `HEAD` to the name *without* creating it.  This is the same state we had with the totally-empty repository (well, except of course that it is actually *possible* to create branch names: Git simply chose *not* to create it right now).

The `--orphan` option was new in Git 1.7.2 (it's called out in the [release notes](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.2.txt)).  It simply puts Git into a state in which the *next* commit you make will be a root commit.  Creating that root commit will create the branch name, pointing to the new commit just created.

What will the *contents* of this next commit be?  The answer is the same as always.  When you run `git commit`, Git writes out whatever is in the *index* as the snapshot for the new commit.  To this snapshot, it adds the metadata from `user.name`, `user.email`, your log message, and so on.  It also adds the parent of the current commit—or in this case, *no* parent since you're on a branch that doesn't exist.  That makes this new commit a root commit, with content from the index, and metadata as usual.

In your particular case, you'd like the content—the snapshot—to mirror that of an existing commit.  So you *can* use `git checkout --orphan`, if you have it—if your Git is at least 1.7.2—by first checking out the existing commit, `286f295` or `Super_Branch`:

```
git checkout 286f295         # detached HEAD, or
git checkout Super_Branch    # HEAD attached to Super_Branch
```

This fills your index and work-tree from commit `286f295`.  (Make sure you're not also carrying uncommitted changes: see [Checkout another branch when there are uncommitted changes on the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452).)  Then you simply `git checkout --orphan` a new branch name—you can't use `Super_Branch`, as that name already exists:

```
git checkout --orphan tiny_tim
```

and then `git commit` to supply a new log message and use the current date-and-time and so on.

But: what if your Git is older than 1.7.2, or you want to re-use the log message from commit `286f295`?  Here, you can cheat: use `git commit-tree` directly.  The `git commit-tree` command creates a commit given some existing snapshot—a *tree object*, in Git internal-speak—with the log message coming from its standard input.  So:

```
git log --no-walk --pretty=format:%B 286f295
```

will extract the commit message from `286f295`.  Piping that to `git commit-tree` will set the log message the way you want.  (You will still be the author and committer of the new commit, made "now.")  Hence:

```
git log --no-walk --pretty=format:%B 286f295 | git commit-tree 286f295^{tree}
```

will create the desired root commit, and print out its hash ID.

Now you simply need to create a branch name, pointing to the new commit:

```
git branch tiny_tim <hash-id>
```

where *`hash_id`* is from the `git commit-tree` command.

Comment: Okay, so if I understood correctly, that's the way to create a "copy" of one commit (that's my bad for creating to simple example); what if my branch has several commits and I want to "copy" all of them, recreating their order?

Comment: If you have N commits you'd like to sort of strand like that, you'll need to create a root commit copy for the first of the N commits, then create additional copies for each subsequent commit. Each copy can re-use the stored snapshot of the corresponding original commit, but needs a new and different parent (or parents). The only "easy" way to do this is with `git filter-branch`: use the `--commit-filter` to remove the parent(s) of the commit that you'd like to make into a root commit, and leave all other commits unmodified as filter-branch will handle the parent adjustment.

Comment: (The filter-branch command is generally not easy to use, but once you understand that what you're really doing here is manipulating commit parent hash IDs, it's straightforward enough.) Note that filter-branch will insist on updating some branch name(s) after doing the commit copies, so you'll generally start by creating the new name that you want, using `git branch`.